# Javascript create new array from given array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, merge

I have an array of objects containing num and sum

```
[
   {num: 1, sum: 10},
   {num: 1, sum: 2},
   {num: 1, sum: 3},
   {num: 2, sum: 1},
   {num: 2, sum: 40},
   {num: 2, sum: 100},
   {num: 3, sum: 0},
   {num: 4, sum: 0},
]
```

How I want is:

```
[
   {1: {count: 3, totalSum: 15},
   {2: {count: 3, totalSum: 141},
   {3: {count: 1, totalSum: 0},
   {4: {count: 1, totalSum: 0},
]
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: post code sample, how far you have tried

Comment: What did you try so far? Show us some code

Comment: Your desired structure is invalid, you opened braces, but never closed those.

Comment: Are you sure thats the output you want? Wouldnt you be better to have a single object with keys 1,2,3,4?

Comment: Result structure doesn't make much sense either. Why would you want to use `num` as key for nested objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to `reduce` into an object indexed by `num`s, and then `map` that object into an array:

```js
const input=[{num:1,sum:10},{num:1,sum:2},{num:1,sum:3},{num:2,sum:1},{num:2,sum:40},{num:2,sum:100},{num:3,sum:0},{num:4,sum:0},]
const outputObj = input.reduce((a, { num, sum }) => {
  if (!a[num]) a[num] = { count: 0, totalSum: 0 };
  a[num].count++;
  a[num].totalSum += sum;
  return a;
}, {});
const output = Object.entries(outputObj)
  .map(([key, val]) => ({ [key] : val }));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: That's an interesting solution: `grouping` and `counting` in the same function. Congrats.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` method in order to group the array and then use another `reduce` method in order to find `count` and `totalSum` properties for every key.

```js
let arr = [ {num: 1, sum: 10}, {num: 1, sum: 2}, {num: 1, sum: 3}, {num: 2, sum: 1}, {num: 2, sum: 40}, {num: 2, sum: 100}, {num: 3, sum: 0}, {num: 4, sum: 0}, ]

var groupBy = function(arr, key) {
  return arr.reduce(function(acc, x) {
    (acc[x[key]] = acc[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return acc;
  }, {});
};

let grouped = groupBy(arr, 'num');

let result = Object.keys(grouped).reduce(function(acc, key){
  let obj ={ [key] :  {count : grouped[key].length, totalSum: grouped[key].map(a => a.sum).reduce((a,b) => a + b)}}
  acc.push(obj)
  return acc;
},[]);
console.log(result);
```